# how to insert Data into SQL Database?

Tags: database, vb.net, azure-sql-database, sql-insert

In the Database, I used an assigned `ProgName = varchar`,`MaleCuteOff = int`,`FemaleCutOff=int`, and I'm trying to collect User input for the values, but I'm getting an **Error**

> Conversion from string "INSERT INTO CutOff_Point((ProgN" to type
> integer is not valid.

```
Sub save()

    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO CutOff_Point (ProgName, MaleCutOff, FemaleCutOff) VALUES (@colProg, @colMale, @colFemale)"
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=UEW_ADMISSION_CHEAKER;Integrated Security=True")
        Using com As New SqlCommand()
            With com
                .Connection = con
                .CommandType = query
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colProg", cmbProg.SelectedItem.ToString)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colMale", txtMaleCut.Text.ToString)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colFemale", txtFemaleCut.Text.ToString)

            End With
            Try
                con.Open()
                com.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Catch ex As SqlException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Saving data Not Complete")

            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Trivial error: It is _CommandText = query_ not _CommandType = query_

Comment: Why are you using `Strings` to set the last two parameters if those columns are type `int`? Apart from that, what's the point of calling `ToString` on a `String`? You're doing it all over. `ex.Message` is also a `String` so why would you call `ToString` on it? That suggests that you're not really thinking about you're data types and just calling `ToString` willy-nilly.

Comment: thanks soo much, i had alot of confusion on my mind

Comment: Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 1):

This:

```vb
.CommandType = query
```

should be setting `Commandtext`, not `CommandType`. Why set those properties like that in the first place, when you can use the constructor?

```vb
Using com As New SqlCommand(query, con)
```